# MariaDB Window Function (LAG)

Tags: sql, mariadb, window-functions

I'm trying to get the difference in revenue between consecutive trading months using a LAG function to look at the preceding month's figures. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(`Invoice_Date`) AS 'Month', 
    ROUND(SUM(`Sales_Total`),2) AS 'revenue_month',
    LAG(SUM(`Sales_Total`), 1) OVER (ORDER BY MONTH(`Invoice_Date`)) AS 'revenue_previous_month'
FROM `sales_2021`
GROUP BY MONTH(`Invoice_Date`)
ORDER BY MONTH(`Invoice_Date`);
```

Trying this in phpMyAdmin first shows an error for the alias `'revenue_previous_month'` saying  **alias previously found**. I tried removing the alias, but then I just get an error saying **#1111 - Invalid use of group function**

It does seem to be the LAG function causing the issue as removing that line altogether means the query works no problem, but I can't see anything in the line which might cause issues.

I'm pretty new to WINDOW functions and this is my first time trying LAG to get a value from the preceding row, so I'm sure I probably missed something basic, but I can't find out what!

Help please!

Comment: @James MySql 8.0+ supports window functions and a window function over an aggregate is supported as well. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=56440a2784c187fe688a5f21d8d375b8)

Comment: @Serg I'm running MySQL v10.4, but I can't get this working. To be sure James solution does sort of work, but I really need to be looking at the aggregated figures and I just wind up back with the original error. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 10.4 is a MariaDB version, not MySQL. These are two different products. Their implementations of window functions are based on different code. They are bound to work differently. MariaDB shares a lot of code with MySQL, but they forked in 2010 and they have both been changing since then. You should not think of MariaDB as compatible with MySQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin Many thanks for that Bill. I'm learning this stuff on my own and had no idea about the divergence. I've managed to get Xampp up and running with MySQL now as opposed to MariaDB and everything now works fine!

Comment: The makers of MariaDB depend on folks having that misunderstanding! :)